# Observing nested properties in Ember controller

Tags: checkbox, ember.js, properties, controller, nested

I'm in the middle of a small project involving Ember. It's my very first time at working with this framework and it has not been an easy learning so far :(

Right now I'm having troubles dealing with nested arrays. What I want to do is pretty standard (at least it seems that way): I have items, item categories and category types (just a way to organize them).

The idea is that there are checkboxes (categories) that allow me to filter the items that are shown in the webpage. On the other hand, there are checkboxes (types) that allow me to check multiple catgories at a time.

In order to implement this I've defined a route (in which I retrieve all the data from these models) and a controller. Originally, I only had items and categories. In this context, I observe the changes in the filters (categories) like this: `categories.@each.isChecked` and then show the item selection. Unfortunately, now that the hierarchy is types->categories, is not possible to observe changes in categories in the same manner according to the docs:

> Note that @each only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms like todos.@each.owner.name or todos.@each.owner.@each.name.

I google a little bit but didn't find too much about it, so I right now I was thinking in using a custom view for categories (one that extends the Ember.Checkbox) and send an event to the controller whenever a category is checked or unchecked. Is more of a "manual" work and I guess is far from Ember's way of dealing with this type of things.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this would be to observe the category types and filter categories, the same way that the categories are being observed.

This is an example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/naqebijebapa/1/edit

*(one to many relationships have been assumed)*

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each catType in catTypes}}

      <li>{{input type="checkbox" checked=catType.isSelected }}{{catType.id}} - {{catType.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  <hr/>
  <ul>
    {{#each cat in filteredCats}}

      <li>{{input type="checkbox" checked=cat.isSelected }}{{cat.id}} - {{cat.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  <hr/>
    <ul>
    {{#each item in filteredItems}}
      <li>{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.CategoryType = Em.Object.extend({
  id:null,
  name:null,
  isSelected:true
});

App.Category = Em.Object.extend({
  id:null,
  name:null,
  type:null,
  isSelected:false
});

var catTypeData = [
  App.CategoryType.create({id:1,name:"type1"}),
  App.CategoryType.create({id:2,name:"type2"}),
  App.CategoryType.create({id:3,name:"type3"}),
  App.CategoryType.create({id:4,name:"type4"})
];

var catData = [
  App.Category.create({id:1,name:"cat1",type:catTypeData[1]}),
  App.Category.create({id:2,name:"cat2",type:catTypeData[2]}),
  App.Category.create({id:3,name:"cat3",type:catTypeData[0]})
];

var itemsData = [
  {id:1,name:"item1",cat:catData[0]},
  {id:2,name:"item2",cat:catData[0]},
  {id:3,name:"item3",cat:catData[1]}
];


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({catTypes:catTypeData,cats:catData,items:itemsData});
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  filteredItems:[],
  filterItemsBasedOnCategory:function(){
    var selectedCats = this.get("cats").filterBy("isSelected");
    if(!Em.isEmpty(selectedCats))
    this.set("filteredItems",this.get("items").filter(function(item){
      return selectedCats.contains(item.cat);}));
    else
      this.set("filteredItems",[]);
  }.observes("cats.@each.isSelected"),
  filterCatsBasedOnCategoryType:function(){
    var selectedCatTypes = this.get("catTypes").filterBy("isSelected");
    if(!Em.isEmpty(selectedCatTypes))
    this.set("filteredCats",this.get("cats").filter(function(cat){
      var itContainsIt = selectedCatTypes.contains(cat.type);
      if(!itContainsIt){
        cat.set("isSelected",false);
      }
      return itContainsIt;
    }));
    else
      this.set("filteredCats",[]);
  }.observes("catTypes.@each.isSelected")
});
```